# is flutter widget tree stable during Navigator operations

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

I have an application that is composed as follows:
MaterialApp -> SettingsWidget -> MainScreen.

where MaterialsApp is provided by flutter, SettingsWidget is an Inherited widget that saves some user preferences, and MainScreen is the landing page of the application.

in the MainScreen, the user can push a button to open the Settings Screen, all the settings should of course be preserved at least during the application life time (I'm learning, so I don't care about how to properly store these preferences).

To navigate between the main screen and setting screen I used

```dart
Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
  MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (context) {
      // return requestedScreen; 
      // this was an old version, 
      // that caused the settings widget to sink in the widget tree,
      // as I saw from the dart dev tools
      return FilterSettings(child: requestedScreen);
    }
  )
)
```

However as you might have guessed, whenever the user navigates a new settings widget is re-created and user preferred settings are dropped, I tried to transfer the user setting data from the old widget to the new one, but `FilterSetting.of(context)` raised an assertion exception that it couldn't find a FilterSetting widget in the tree.

The question is, "is the widgets tree stable during pushReplacement?"

any other comments or suggestion on the code are welcome, but are not required, answer backed with links or docs is highly appreciated.

Please note that I've figured a simple workaround, but I still want to know the widget tree status inside the navigator, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

flutter does not save the settings:
you can use [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) package

the setting you change is data, after reloading, the setting you changed are back to normal  so you have to save them in a database

`shared_preference` is simple and is good for data like this

Comment: I'm aware of that as I said in the question, I'm learning through this project, and I'm curious whether Navigator destabilize the widget tree.

Comment: when you navigate the StateFullwidget rebuilts and the state is lost

Comment: if you have a reference please consider submitting it as answer.